# arrow function confusing in exporting

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a abc.js that has this

```
export function doSomething() { ... }
```

then I can include in somewhere like so

```
import { doSomething } from './abc'
doSomething()
```

but I can't use arrow function in abc.js like

```
export const doSomething = () => {}
```

why?

Comment: Of course you can. Why do you think you can't? Are you getting any errors when you try?

Comment: @Bergi yes just tried that out, previous I didn't use the const for the function name.

Comment: So it's working now? In that case, you might as well delete the question.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because you are exporting the arrow function and defining it at the same time, which is an invalid syntax.
Try this and it will work:

```
const doSomething = () => {};
export default doSomething;
```

Comment: wouldn't it be `export {doSomething };` so that `import { doSomething } from './abc'` works?

Comment: means I can't do for multiple arrow function? default can be used once.

Comment: `export const x = …` is *not* invalid syntax. And it's not supposed to be a default export anyway?